# Any way for nasm to automatically add used external symbols?

Tags: linux, nasm, elf

Is there any way for NASM to generate extern declarations automatically for any undeclared symbol it finds?

What I have now:

- a source file for my app
- a large include with all the GL_ defines and ~500 of OpenGL functions declared as extern gl* (made from gl.h)

This of course generates an adequately large relocation table as a result.

But I am using only a small percentage of all the declared OpenGL functions and I would like to include only those that I have used, possibly without having to declare the externs by myself at all?

Or should I stick to my previous way of doing this and manually declaring every new extern as soon as I need it?

I did read the NASMdocs and did a search, but all I found is how to declare externs and how to use them between .o files, which is not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research I managed to find a solution to this: stripping.

First, I build my objects and executable as normal, including in them the large relocation tables. But at each step I add `strip --strip-unneeded` - both for intermediate objects and for the final executable.

What it does, it leaves only the symbols that were actually used in the objects, while removing all the others. It does add a bit of overhead to the compilation process, but it's mostly unnoticeable.

I have also found that stripping both the `.o` files, as well as the executable produces the smallest file. I suppose there are new symbols added while linking and some of them are unused and thus can be stripped.

It's very easy to do by adding this to the Makefile.